# remote mysql connection timed out

Tags: linux, mysql

I have a client on `linux` and the `mysql server on windows`

I wanted to connect to mysql remotely 2 computers can ping each other without any problem in mysql server I set the permission correctly so the specified client is allowed to connect

```
WIN IP:  192.168.1.2
Linux IP:192.168.1.3
```

in windows system:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'parsa'@'192.168.1.3' IDENTIFIED BY 'parsa';
flush all privileges;
```

in my linux,in my.cnf I wrote this line in `mysqld` section

```
bind-address=192.168.1.2
```

skip-networking was commented and I didn't change it I restarted the mysql

when I use

```
telnet 192.168.1.2 3306 

telnet:connect to address 192.168.1.2:Connection timed out
```

and using this command:

```
mysql -h 192.168.1.2 -u parsa -p parsa
Error 2003:can't connect to mysql server on 192.168.1.2
```

The `firewalls` in both sides are disabled what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure that the server instance is running on the windows machine? You can verify this by doing `C:\> sc query MySQL` in cmd.exe on Windows. If it's not running try running it with... `C:\> sc start MySQL`. For more information I found [this website](http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Error2003-CantConnectToMySQLServer) to be helpful.